# Integrate $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x}\frac{\sinh(ax)}{\sinh(bx)}e^{-cx}\,dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, complex-integration

I am trying to evaluate the integral

$$ 
\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x}\frac{\sinh(ax)}{\sinh(bx)}e^{-cx}\,dx
$$

with $c>0$ and $0<a<b$.

I have tried to look for a suitable contour, or to differentiate under integral sign with respect to $c$ (as I would do without the sinh's), but without success.

Thank you in advance for any hint!

Comment: I would think that a rectangular contour encasing the first pole of $\sinh(bx)$ would do. You may need to make the left side of the contour occur at $-\frac{1}{n}$ or something though so that you don't hit the pole.

Comment: Likely no chance. Mathematica 12.2 fails even with `Integrate[Sin[x]/x*Sinh[2*x]/Sinh[3*x]*Exp[-x], {x, 0, Infinity}]`.

Comment: When $c=0$ the integral is $$\arctan\left(\tan\left(\frac{a\pi}{2b}\right)\tanh\left(\frac{\pi}{2b}\right)\right)$$ While I couldn't find this exact integral, you may be able to manipulate other integrals with this one from G&R.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let

$$ 
I(a)= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sinh(tx)\sinh(ax)\cosh(cx)}{(tx)\sinh(bx)}\,dx
$$
Then
\begin{align}
I’(a) &
= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sinh(tx)\cosh(ax)\cosh(cx)}{t\sinh(bx)}\,dx\\
&= \frac1{4t}[J(a+c+t)-J(a-c-t) +J(a-c+t)- J(a+c-t)]
\end{align}
where
$$J(p) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sinh(px)}{\sinh(bx)}\,dx
=\frac\pi b \tan\frac{\pi p}{2b}
$$
(obtained with contour integration.) Apply $\int_0^a \tan s\>ds=\ln \sec a$ to get

$$I(a) = \int_0^a I’(s)ds=\frac1{2t}
\ln \frac{\sec\frac{\pi(a+c+t)}{2b}}
{\sec\frac{\pi(a+c-t)}{2b}}
+ \frac1{2t}
\ln \frac{\sec\frac{\pi(a-c+t)}{2b} }
{\sec\frac{\pi(a-c-t)}{2b} }
$$

Finally, with $\frac{\sec(u+i v)}
{\sec(u-i v)}=\frac{1+i \tan u\tanh v}{1-i \tan u\tanh v}
$

\begin{align}
& \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x\sinh(ax)}{x\sinh(bx)}e^{-cx}\,dx
=\frac12 I(a)|_{t=i}\\=&
\frac12\tan^{-1}\left( \tan\frac{\pi(a+c)}{2b}\tanh\frac\pi{2b} \right)
+ \frac12\tan^{-1}\left( \tan\frac{\pi(a-c)}{2b}\tanh\frac\pi{2b} \right)
\end{align}

Comment: Very nicely done. I expanded the $\sin$ piece by piece to get the series
$$ \frac{\psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{a+b+c}{2 b}\right)-\psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{-a+b+c}{2 b}\right)}{2 b} - \sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^k \left(\zeta \left(2 k+1,\frac{-a+b+c}{2 b}\right)-\zeta \left(2 k+1,\frac{a+b+c}{2 b}\right)\right)}{(2 k+1) (2 b)^{2 k+1}} $$
Which is equivalent to your answer.

Comment: Really, very nice solution for $I(a)= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sinh(tx)\sinh(ax)\cosh(cx)}{(tx)\sinh(bx)}\,dx$, but $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x}\frac{\sinh(ax)}{\sinh(bx)}e^{-cx}\,dx\neq\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sinh(tx)\sinh(ax)\cosh(cx)}{(tx)\sinh(bx)}\,dx$. Or, more simple: $\int_0^{\infty}e^{-cx}dx\neq\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\cosh cxdx$ Unfortunately, the symmetry of integration from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ cannot be used here...

Comment: @Svyatoslav - you’re right. I thought the lower limit was $-\infty$; otherwise an intractable integral

Comment: Your solution for $(-\infty;\infty)$ is really outstanding

Comment: This is a superb solution !

Comment: Thank you, very nice work! I think I should now be able to complete the missing piece (writing $e^{-cx}=\cosh(cx)-\sinh(cx)$ and being careful in separating the terms that appear upon differentiating with respect to $a$).